# Haskell - Attempting Monad instance - syntax issues

Tags: haskell, monads

I have the following definitions:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> [(a,String)] }


instance Functor Parser where
 fmap g (Parser pa) = Parser { parse = \s -> [(g a,s') | (a,s') <- pa s] }


instance Applicative Parser where
 pure x = Parser { parse = \s -> [(x,s)] }
 (<*>) (Parser pg) (Parser pa) = Parser { parse = \s -> [(g a,s'') | (g,s') <- pg s, (a, s'') <- pa s'] }



instance Monad Parser where
 return = pure
 (>>=) (Parser pa) g = Parser { parse = \s -> [(b,s'') | [(a, s')] <- (pa s), [(b,s'')] <- (g a) s'] }
```

The trouble is with the bind operator implementation. I am not sure why I get type error there. I am attempting to define the bind operator on the same lines as (<*>)

The error is:

```
parser.hs:17:58: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, String)’
                  with actual type ‘[(a, t0)]’
    • In the pattern: [(a, s')]
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: [(a, s')] <- (pa s)
      In the expression:
        [(b, s'') | [(a, s')] <- (pa s), [(b, s'')] <- (g a) s']
    • Relevant bindings include
        g :: a -> Parser b (bound at parser.hs:17:20)
        pa :: String -> [(a, String)] (bound at parser.hs:17:16)
        (>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
          (bound at parser.hs:17:2)
   |
17 |  (>>=) (Parser pa) g = Parser { parse = \s -> [(b,s'') | [(a, s')] <- (pa s), [(b,s'')] <- (g a) s'] }
   |                                                          ^^^^^^^^^

parser.hs:17:92: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 -> [[(b, String)]]’
                  with actual type ‘Parser b’
    • The function ‘g’ is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘a -> Parser b’ has only one
      In the expression: (g a) s'
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: [(b, s'')] <- (g a) s'
    • Relevant bindings include
        s' :: t0 (bound at parser.hs:17:63)
        g :: a -> Parser b (bound at parser.hs:17:20)
        (>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
          (bound at parser.hs:17:2)
   |
17 |  (>>=) (Parser pa) g = Parser { parse = \s -> [(b,s'') | [(a, s')] <- (pa s), [(b,s'')] <- (g a) s'] }
```

Update:
For the sake of completeness, based on the answers. Here is what worked:

```
instance Monad Parser where
 return = pure
 (>>=) (Parser pa) g = Parser { parse = \s -> [(b,s'') | (a, s') <- (pa s), (b,s'') <- parse (g a) s'] }
```

Comment: The result of `pa s` is a list of pairs. So it should be `(a, s') <- (pa s)`. Using `[(a, s')]` you are saying that `pa s` returns a `[[(a, String)]]` instead of `[(a, String)]`.

Comment: With this change: (>>=) (Parser pa) g = Parser { parse = \s -> [(b,s'') | (a, s') <- (pa s), (b,s'') <- (g a) s'] }  (g a) s' still complains that 'g' has been applied to two parameters, I cant see how though

Comment: Got it has to be:  parse (g a) s'] }

Comment: Minor note: usually, one can avoid defining both `<*>` and `>>=` (even if it's a nice exercise to do so). In fact, on can define only `>>=` and simply write `(<*>) = ap` (where `ap` is imported from `Control.Monad`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guard pattern like `[(a, s')] <- (pa s)` means you're expecting `pa s` to return a list of lists with each exactly one pair of `a` and `s` in them, whereas it actually returns just a list with any number of those pairs in them.

Basically, drop the brackets (and also from the other binding) and then it should work.